# Create trigger only if it doesn't exist on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm writing a script to create a trigger on a table in MySQL, but there's a possibility that the trigger might already exist.

Is this something I need to worry about, or will creating the trigger overwrite any trigger with the same name?

I considered using a `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS` statement before the `CREATE TRIGGER...`. Will that have any performance penalties or other downsides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS is exactly the way to do it. The only downside is if you did not know about a trigger, and it has *exactly* the same name (possible if following naming conventions), then you would effectively lose the definition and functionality behind it.

> will creating the trigger overwrite any trigger with the same name?

No, it will fail with an error, actually.